# Using onClick to change activities causes crash

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio

The title does not exactly describe my problem, but I am unsure how else to title this succinctly.

My program has a button that, when clicked, should "quit" current activity and change to a new activity, called "ScorePage.java". When I set the onClick behavior of the button to the method "quit," the program crashes when I click the button. However, If I set the onClick behavior to the method "callQuit," the button works as intended.

The second method seems redundant since all it does is call the first method, so why does it work?

NOTE: the "quit" and "callQuit" methods are part of the current activity, called "QuestsionsPage.java"

```
public void quit(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScorePage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void callQuit(View view)
{
    quit(view);
}
```

Comment: need more code and stacktrace

Comment: quit() is the first method I listed

Comment: Use _YourActivity.this_ instead of _this_ only

Comment: Please add stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this it works for me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.txtQuit);
}

public void quit(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

and in xml i wrote this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtQuit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="quit"
    android:text="@string/quit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change some code of callQuite method as below.

```
public void callQuit(View view)
{ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScorePage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}
```